# INline multiple condition with ng-bind in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to use something like below:

```
<span ng-bind="rep.newDate.match('.*FNFx.*')?'NotAvailable':(rep.value===''?'?':rep.value)"></span>
```

But it's not working. How to correct it?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Is there an error in the console? What kind of values might `rep.newDate` be?

Comment: If rep.value is empty it should print '?' in span ..but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I problem I feel is you cannot use JavaScript's `match` function as it is in the template. This is because it is not in angular's scope.

To resolve this, create a function in your controller for doing the regex part as follows:

```
$scope.matchPattern = function(date) {
    return date.match('.*FNFx.*')
}
```

and change your `ng-bind` to:

```
ng-bind="matchPattern(rep.newDate)?'NotAvailable':(rep.value===''?'?':rep.value)"
```

Comment: Pattern is working fine but when condition is false and then second condition rep.value ==='' should be validated ..I dnt know whether it's correct syntax or nt

Comment: syntax looks fine to me...perhaps you can recreate this problem in a plunker?